# How to use grouping at class level in testng with gradle build

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, testng

While calling from the terminal. throwing null pointer for teardown and setUp method

@Test(groups = {'G1'})
    public testClass(){

```
    @BeforeMethod`enter code here`
    setUp(){}

    @AfterMethod
    tearDown(){}

    @Test(groups = {'G2'}
    public void testmethod_1(){}
    @Test
    public void testmethod_2(){}

}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperties = [
            tag: System.getProperty('tag', 'G1'),
            tag: System.getProperty('tag', 'G2')
    ]
}
task runTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {## Heading ##
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        includeGroups System.getProperty('tag', 'NONE')
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of that exception

Comment: Was getting Null pointer exception